# How can I get all elements from a list into a comma separated string?

Tags: apex, list

I have populated a list with a class.

Here is the query which is filling the list of Customers:

```
List<Customers> customers = [Select Id, LegacyCustomerNo FROM Customer__c WHERE state__c = 'PA'];
```

Is there any method that will let me get all the Ids in a comma separated string?

Is it also possible to get all the values for legacycustomerno field in a comma separated string?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @BrianMansfield Understanding apex is my purpose for this specific post. I have solved this by looping through the list, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup..

```
List<Customer__c> customers = [Select Id, LegacyCustomerNo__c FROM Customer__c WHERE state__c = 'PA'];
String[] tmp1 = New String[]{};
String[] tmp2 = New String[]{};
String idString, customernostring;

for(Customers__c c : customers__c){
   tmp1.add(c.id);
   tmp2.add(c.legacycustomerno__c);
}

idString = string.join(tmp1,',');
customernostring = string.join(tmp2,',');
```

Comment: String.Join() usage is what I was looking for, but I suspect the loop is unavoidable.

Comment: For the ID field specifically, there's a more concise (if not awkward) syntax: `String ids = String.join( new List<String>( new Map<Id, SObject>(customers).keySet() ), ',');` Basically, construct a Map by ID, grab its keySet, convert from a set to a list, then join the result. This doesn't work for other fields, so you'd still need your for-each loop to get LegacyCustomerNo field.

Answer (score 4):

The method you're looking for is `String.join(Iterable object, String separator)`

You won't be able to do what you want directly from your `List<Customer__c>`. Instead, you put your query directly into a for loop, and build the two lists (to be turned into comma-separated strings) at the same time.

From there, you can call `String.join()` to get your comma-separated strings.

```
List<String> idList = new List<String>();
List<String> legacyNumList = new List<String>();

for(Customer__c cust :  [Select Id, LegacyCustomerNo FROM Customer__c WHERE state__c = 'PA']){
    idList.add(cust.Id);
    legacyNumList.add(cust.LegacyCustomerNo);
}

String commaSepIds = String.join(idList, ', ');
String commaSepLegacy = String.join(legacyNumList, ', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List customers = [Select Id, LegacyCustomerNo__c FROM Customer__c WHERE state__c = 'PA'];
String[] tmp1 = New String[]{};
String[] tmp2 = New String[]{};
String idString, customernostring;

for(Customers__c c : customers__c){
   tmp1.add(c.id);
   tmp2.add(c.legacycustomerno__c);
}

idString = string.join(tmp1,',');
customernostring = string.join(tmp2,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change your datatype a bit, you could use a `Map`.

```
Map<ID, Customer__C> customersMap = new Map<ID, Customer__C>([Select Id, LegacyCustomerNo FROM Customer__c WHERE state__c = 'PA']);
String custIDs = String.join(customersMap.keySet(), ',');
```

Unfortunately Apex doesn't have lamda expressions, so I'm not aware of any way to do a trick like this with any field but ID.  Since you mentioned you would like to understand Apex better, another solution which gives you a reusable method would be to create a static method like this:

```
public static String joinSObjectField(List<sObject> objs, string field, string separator)
{
    integer lastIndex = objs.size() - 1;
    string ret = '';
    for (integer i = 0; i < lastIndex; ++i)
        ret += String.valueOf(objs[i].get(field)) + separator;
    ret += String.valueOf(objs[lastIndex].get(field));
    return ret;
}
```

This could then be called as

```
List<customer__c> customers = [Select Id, LegacyCustomerNo FROM Customer__c WHERE state__c = 'PA'];
String legacyids = joinSObjectField(customers, 'LegacyCustomerNo'/*__c?*/, ',');
```

Of course, this will pass over the list twice if you use it two times, unlike the other solutions which only pass over once and do twice the work with each pass, but if you need to get more than one field as a joined string on a lot of sObject lists you could easily extend this to take a list of fields to join.